# Win32 SetTimer Debugging in OlyDbg

Tags: assembly, x86

I am relatively new to reverse engineering in OlyDbg but I'm trying to debug a small application I made in Vb.Net that uses a timer.

Essentially, when the application loads, there is a timer that counts down from 7 to 0, when it reaches 0 a button enables that allows the application to load.

I am trying to reverse engineer this in Olydbg to see how SetTimer works but I'm struggling. My goal is to modify the assembly to be able to manipulate the starting value (which is hard coded as 7).

I believe I have traced where the SetTimer is called:

```
0040E316 | FF15 74A54E00            | call dword ptr ds:[<&SetTimer>]         |
```

Following this location in OlyDBG takes me to this:

```
76A1F190 | 8BFF                     | mov edi,edi                             |
76A1F192 | 55                       | push ebp                                |
76A1F193 | 8BEC                     | mov ebp,esp                             |
76A1F195 | 6A 00                    | push 0                                  |
76A1F197 | FF75 14                  | push dword ptr ss:[ebp+14]              |
76A1F19A | FF75 10                  | push dword ptr ss:[ebp+10]              |
76A1F19D | FF75 0C                  | push dword ptr ss:[ebp+C]               |
76A1F1A0 | FF75 08                  | push dword ptr ss:[ebp+8]               |
76A1F1A3 | FF15 8C3BA976            | call dword ptr ds:[<&NtUserSetTimer>]   |
76A1F1A9 | 5D                       | pop ebp                                 |
76A1F1AA | C2 1000                  | ret 10                                  |
```

I've looked at Microsoft documenation regarding SetTimer to see what parameters are required but I'm kind of lost at this point. I assumed the interval parameter (which I'm guessing would be 1000 in decimal as milliseconds) would be in one of these PUSH commands but manipulating these values doesn't seem to have any effect.

Can anybody provide some pointers or guidance as to where I can go from here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're debugging `SetTimer`, that's an API and there is no need to RE it unless you want to know how *Windows* (and not your app) work. VB.NET is compiled to IL bytecode. That's very very easy to disassemble and even decompile (unless heavily obfuscated). Those IL instructions are translated into x86 native instructions by the .NET jitter. What do you want to RE, the .NET code or the generated x86 assembly? Too see the x86 assembly, [better method exists](https://adamsitnik.com/Disassembly-Diagnoser/) (first link found, check it). To RE the .NET code use a .NET decompiler.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to RE the X86 assembly really, its more for my personal learning, I was hoping to be able to manipulate the assembly to alter the start time mainly.

Comment: The point is that the start time is hardcoded inside the IL of you application, when that code is read by the jitter the start time (being a constant) will be present in the x86 assembly too. But this code is generated on the fly, possibly reusing the same memory area of previous jitted code and being overwritten lately by other jitted code. So you need to peek at it at the right time. You can set an HW breakpoint on the address of the IL code that contains the start time (use .NET dissambler and either look for the IL bytes in the binary or compute the instruction address manually) ...

Comment: ... The HW breakpoint is of type Byte, Access. This will make it break when the JIT try to read the IL. Then use the debug symbols of MSCOREE.DLL to help follow the internals until the JIT writes the relative x86 instructions. Find where the start time is used and edit it. Be sure to know HOW the start time is encoded, it is likely to be a sort of numbers of chrono units (ns? seconds?) from a specific point in time. Not easy to recognise at first. If you also post you vb.net code one could advise specifically. BTW there's a specific site (re.stackexchange.com) for RE.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! I will carry on with the debugging now I know more of what I'm looking for :)